# How add a plugin with data to a page using the add_plugin (API)?

Tags: django-cms

i'm trying to add a plugin in a placeholder of a page when i save a model. But i don't know how to pass the parameter "data" to add_plugin() function of the API.

This is how i'm calling the function

```
page = create_page(self.title, 'page.html', 'es', parent=query_pages[0])
placeholder = page.placeholders.get(slot='News Header')
add_plugin(placeholder, 'ArticlePluginPublisher', 'es', **query_art[0].article)
```

And when i call add_plugin appears the next error

> add_plugin() argument after ** must be a mapping, not Article

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the [docs](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/api_references.html#cms.api.add_plugin)? `**query_art[0].article` doesn't match the expected arguments as it's an instance;

- placeholder (cms.models.placeholdermodel.Placeholder instance) – Placeholder to add the plugin to
- plugin_type (string or cms.plugin_base.CMSPluginBase sub-class, must be a valid plugin) – What type of plugin to add
- language (string) – Language code for this plugin, must be in LANGUAGES
- position (string) – Position to add this plugin to the placeholder, must be a valid django-mptt position
- target – Parent plugin. Must be plugin instance
- data (kwargs) – Data for the plugin type instance

Data is expected to be something like a dictionary, or something that supports the `**` unpacking syntax;

```
add_plugin(placeholder, 'ArticlePluginPublisher', 'es', **{'article': query_art[0].article})
```

Check out this example of data or kwargs in a function call;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1769475/1199464